# How to document all commands that I used in Vim editor in a special file?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, terminal

I need to document all commands that I used to modify text using [Vim editor](https://www.vim.org/). When I am in the terminal and need to save all my input in a file I usually write:

```
history > ~/some_file.txt
```

However, I am not sure how to do it while using vim. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 2):

Any output can be redirected with `:redir`. So

```
redir >~/vim.history|silent history|redir END
```

Will redirect the output of `:history` to the file `~/vim.history`. Here `silent` is used to prevent a `-- More --` prompt.

You could also put the history into the current buffer with

```
:put =execute(':history')
```

Note that Vims history is limited to 50 entries by default (see `:help 'history`).

Answer (score 1):

Use startup [option `-w`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-w). From the docs:

> All the characters that you type are recorded in the file "scriptout", until you exit Vim.  This is useful if you want to create a script file to be used with "vim -s" or ":source!".

Answer (score 0):

1. Press `qx`, which causes Vim to start recording your keystrokes.
2. Press `q` to finish recording.
3. Move your cursor to wherever you would like Vim to paste the record it has just made.
4. Press `"xp` to paste the record.

The `x` identifies a buffer. Buffers `y`, `z` and so on also exist, so you can use a different letter than `x` if you wish.

Nothing requires you to paste the record into the file you were editing when the record was made, incidentally. To paste into a different file, give the command `:tabedit name-of-different-file`, press [Enter], and then press `"xp` to paste. (Since `:tabedit` opens the second files in another *tab,* you can then press `gt` to toggle between the two if you wish.)